# How to find the dimensions of an object using realsense (L515 camera)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, point-clouds, realsense

i have a realsense l 515 camera. I want to find the size of an object inside. In my case, i am running darknet to detect a dummy object. Now Once the object is detected, i want to use the depth frame and the color frame to calculate the length and breadth of the object(roughly). For example, an apple. The bounding box is drawn around the apple. Now , how do i use this bounding box data along with the color frame and depth frame to find the dimensions of the apple? As the bounding box is roughly the size of the apple, i want to convert the pixel coordinates of the bounding box to calculate the dimensions of the apple in real life approximately. I read online about using point clouds but I am new to this, so i am quite unclear how to proceed.

```
import darknet
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs

"""##############. Function definitions. ##################"""

#Define the detection function
def image_detection(image, network, class_names, class_colors, thresh):
    # Darknet doesn't accept numpy images.
    # Create one with image we reuse for each detect
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)

    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (width, height),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, image_resized.tobytes())
    detections = darknet.detect_image(network, class_names, darknet_image, thresh=thresh)
    darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    image = darknet.draw_boxes(detections, image_resized, class_colors)
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), detections


# Initialize and declare the neural network along with data files, config files etc 
quantity_apples = []
config_file = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/yolov4.cfg"
data_file = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/coco.data"
weights = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/yolov4.weights"

network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
        config_file,
        data_file,
        weights,
        batch_size=1
    )

## Realsense from align-depth2color.py

# Create a pipeline
pipeline = rs.pipeline()

# Create a config and configure the pipeline to stream
#  different resolutions of color and depth streams
config = rs.config()

# Get device product line for setting a supporting resolution
pipeline_wrapper = rs.pipeline_wrapper(pipeline)
pipeline_profile = config.resolve(pipeline_wrapper)
device = pipeline_profile.get_device()
device_product_line = str(device.get_info(rs.camera_info.product_line))

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1024, 768, rs.format.z16, 30)

if device_product_line == 'L500':
    print(device_product_line)
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
else:
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

# Start streaming
profile = pipeline.start(config)

# Getting the depth sensor's depth scale (see rs-align example for explanation)
depth_sensor = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor()
depth_scale = depth_sensor.get_depth_scale()
print("Depth Scale is: " , depth_scale)

# We will be removing the background of objects more than
#  clipping_distance_in_meters meters away
clipping_distance_in_meters = 1 #1 meter
clipping_distance = clipping_distance_in_meters / depth_scale

# Create an align object
# rs.align allows us to perform alignment of depth frames to others frames
# The "align_to" is the stream type to which we plan to align depth frames.
align_to = rs.stream.color
align = rs.align(align_to)


# Streaming loop
try:
    for i in range(0,2):
        # Get frameset of color and depth
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        # frames.get_depth_frame() is a 640x360 depth image

        # Align the depth frame to color frame
        aligned_frames = align.process(frames)

        # Get aligned frames
        aligned_depth_frame = aligned_frames.get_depth_frame() # aligned_depth_frame is a 640x480 depth image
        color_frame = aligned_frames.get_color_frame()

        # Validate that both frames are valid
        if not aligned_depth_frame or not color_frame:
            continue

        depth_image = np.asanyarray(aligned_depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        dn_frame_width = 416
        dn_frame_height = 416

        frame_width = color_image.shape[1]
        frame_height = color_image.shape[0]

        #### Passing the image to darknet
        image, detections = image_detection(color_image, network, class_names, class_colors, thresh=0.05)


        for i in range(len(detections)):
            xc_percent = detections[i][2][0]/dn_frame_width
            yc_percent = detections[i][2][1]/dn_frame_height 
            w_percent = detections[i][2][2]/dn_frame_width
            h_percent = detections[i][2][3]/dn_frame_height
            xc = xc_percent*frame_width
            yc = yc_percent*frame_height
            w = w_percent*frame_width
            h = h_percent*frame_height
            xmin = xc - w/2.0
            ymin = yc - h/2.0
            xmax = xc + w/2.0
            ymax = yc + h/2.0


            #If object is detected, increase the count of the object in the frame
            if detections[i][0] == "apple":
                cv2.rectangle(color_image, (int(xmin),int(ymin)),(int(xmax),int(ymax)),(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.putText(color_image, "apple", (int(xmin), int(ymin-10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0,0,255), 2)
        
        #cv2.imwrite(output_path, frame)            
        # Render images:
        #   depth align to color on left
        #   depth on right
        depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        images = np.hstack((color_image, depth_colormap))
        cv2.imwrite("test_images.jpg", color_image)
        #cv2.namedWindow('Align Example', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        #cv2.imshow('Align Example', images)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        # Press esc or 'q' to close the image window
        #if key & 0xFF == ord('q') or key == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            #break
finally:
    pipeline.stop()
```

This is the output image so far. How do i proceed?
[image: output]

Comment: if you dont know the distance between object and camera you can't compute the size, because it could either be a big apple further away or a small apple close to the camera. If you know the distance (e.g. if the realsense camera is a depth/stereo camera) and the intrinsic camera parameters, you can simply compute the size by computing a 3D bounding box around the reconstructed 3D points of your 2D object. 3D reconstruction can be performed by defining the 3D ray from the camera center through the pixel plane and stopping at the known distance (if the depth/stereo camera doesnt provide itself)

Comment: @Micka I have the depth as well. How do i create the 3d bounding box using the output from the depth frame generated by the realsense camera? And how do i compute the reconstruction that you mentioned?

Comment: probably the camera performs the reconstruction for you. How do you receive the depth/3d data from the sensor? 3d bounding box is just min/max x,y,z values of all the points in your 2d bounding box. You could try to cluster/segment the actual object before computing the bounding box.

Comment: @Micka there is a depth frame that store the depth value of every pixel right? how do i use that along with the coordinates of my bounding box? Now there might be multiple apples in the frame so there will be multiple detections, how do i use the bounding boxes obtained from darknet to find the dimensions of my regions of interest i.e apples

Comment: use the depth values inside the bounding box and reconstruct the 3d points of those pixel. You will want to segment the apple a little bit to remove the background depth values. To reconstruct the 3D points, have a look at the kinect tutorial from Nicolas Burrus

Comment: @Micka So, once i reconstruct the 3d points of th epixels, how do i proceed with that data to find the length and breadth of the apple in real life?

Comment: use all the 3D points that belong to the single apple (coarsely you know that from your 2D detection bounding box - maybe you will need a fine segmentation, e.g. from depth clustering) and compute the 3D bounding box from those 3D points.

Comment: @Micka What if just want the 2d size of the object? the length and breadth of the apple? how do i convert the bounding box of the apple into actual dimensions?

Comment: still the 3D  bounding box and just ignore the z axis. You will need the reconstructed 3D points because the 2D image is ambiguous (big object in high distance vs. small object in short distance might have same 2D image size)

Comment: @Micka Do you have the link for the reconstruction of 3d points tutorial by Nicholas? I am unable to find a source for it.

Comment: http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration the computation of P3D is what you need from there. However, many depth cameras have built-in functions in their api to perform that task for you with their built-in intrinsics information. What kind of api/sdk do you use?

Comment: @Micka I am using pyrealsense2 for python as of now. All my code is in python

Comment: probably for reconstruction of 3d points you can simply use https://intelrealsense.github.io/librealsense/python_docs/_generated/pyrealsense2.pointcloud.html  `class pyrealsense2.pointcloud - Generates 3D point clouds based on a depth frame. Can also map textures from a color frame.` together with `map_to(self: pyrealsense2.pointcloud, mapped: pyrealsense2.frame) -  None - Map the point cloud to the given color frame.`

Comment: What will this give me? @Micka

Comment: 3d points and the 2d image positions, so you will know which 3d points belong to the detected o object 2d bounding box